# XQuery find element where child of a matching attribute is empty

Tags: xml, xquery

I have an XML file, to which I am trying to extract the titles of the elements books and journals where the matching product by ID and IDREF has no value in the comments.

So the XML file I have looks something like this:

```
<bookshop>
    <product ID="185.3.16">
        <price currency="AU$">56.85</price>
        <comments>Best sell</comments>
    </product>
    <product ID="163.24.12">
        <price currency="NZ$">28.6</price>
        <comments />
    </product>
    <product ID="332.17.25">
        <price currency="US$">19.95</price>
        <comments></comments>
    </product>
    <book IDREF="163.24.12">
        <title>Core Java</title>
    </book>
    <book IDREF="185.3.16">
        <title>C++ Development</title>
    </book>
    <journal IDREF="332.17.25">
        <title>Mathematics and Computing</title>
    </journal>
</bookshop>
```

And the output I'm trying to achieve is:

```
<title>Core Java</title>
<title>Mathematics and Computing</title>
```

because the book C++ development's IDREF matches the ID of a product whose child comments has no value.

I've tried to create a script using xquery to do so by trying to find all elements product with a distinct ID attribute where it's child comment is also empty, but I'm having trouble both trying to find the products without comments, and then translating those results into something I can return. (I can't really give returning a proper go until I can resolve the products so I haven't been able to make much leeway with that.) But here is what I've tried so far:

```
for $id in distinct-values(//product/@ID)
where count(//product/comments/text()) > 0
return ...?
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"I am trying to extract the titles of the elements books and journals where the matching product by ID and IDREF has no value in the comments"*

**This is one possible XPath to return what you described in question :**

```
/bookshop/*[@IDREF = /bookshop/product[normalize-space(comments) = '']/@ID]/title
```

If you want specifically to select only either `book` or `journal`, simply add a predicate : `[self::book | self::journal]` after `/*`.

**<kbd>[`xpathtester demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/3e478938785432e4510d7ee75bff512c)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
<title>Core Java</title>

<title>Mathematics and Computing</title>
```

---

**UPDATE :**

It isn't clear about the limitation (what kind of XPath expression you can't used). Assuming you are not allowed to use XPath predicate (`[]`), it can be replaced with `where` clause as follow :

```
declare variable emptyProductIDs := /bookshop/product[not(comments/text())]/@ID

for $element in /bookshop/*
where $element/@IDREF = $emptyProductIDs
return $element/title
```

Comment: As much as I would like to use xpath, I'm limited to xquery for this specific use case

Comment: Yes, but this question is part of a small portion of a university assignment, which requires me to use xquery with no xpath involved. Unfortunately, I can't use xpath as much as I'd like to.

Comment: @SteppingHat check **UPDATE** section

Comment: That's what I'm after :) I just needed something that incorporated a set of queries that resulted in the use if a return loop of some sort, rather than just a static xpath query that does it all. Thanks heaps :)